# wxPython: how to determine source of an event

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a Panel with several images on it, each of which is bound to the same event handler. How can I determine which image is being clicked from the event handler? I tried using Event.GetEventObject() but it returns the parent panel instead of the image that was clicked.

Here's some sample code:

```
import math
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1,title="",pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
         size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
         name="frame"):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,pos,size,style,name)

        self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel.SetScrollbars(1,1,1,1)

        num = 4
        cols = 3
        rows = int(math.ceil(num / 3.0))
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=rows,cols=cols)

        filenames = []
        for i in range(num):
            filenames.append("img"+str(i)+".png")
        for fn in filenames:
            img = wx.Image(fn,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
            img2 = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
            img3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,img2)
            sizer.Add(img3)
            img3.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK,self.OnDClick)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def OnDClick(self, event):

        print event.GetEventObject() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 6):

In your loop, give each StaticBitmap widget a unique name. One way to do this would be something like this:

```
wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, 
                wx.BitmapFromImage(img),
                name="bitmap%s" % counter)
```

And then increment the counter at the end. Then in the event handler, do something like this:

```
widget = event.GetEventObject()
print widget.GetName()
```

That's always worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Call `GetId()` on your event in the handler and compare the id it returns to the ids of your staticBitmaps. If you need an example let me know and Ill update my answer

Comment: I tried this on the code I posted above by passing a counter as the id argument to the staticBitmap constructor (0 to n-1). However, calling GetId() on the event always returns -202, for some reason...

Comment: Well theres two ways that you could do it create a list of Id's for your images in advance (and use them when instantiating your staticBitmaps) then just compare them... or put your image objects into a list, then to compare there Ids you can call GetId() on them also, again if you want an example Ill add it... it might be easier to follow..

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that I kinda miss read your comment. If your getting -202 it means your doing something wrong.. if you are actually using the counter.. then you should be getting them numbers back with GetId() an ID of -202 suggests that your passing  a random Id

Comment: @Johnny it's been more than 3 years.. I encountered the same issue.. volting's solution to use GetId() seems best to me.. posted working solution in my answer, in-case you are still interested ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetId(), but make sure you keep it unique across your program. I am posting modified code to show how can you do it. Despite of using filenames as list.

```
def __init__(self, parent, id=-1,title="",pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
     size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
     name="frame"):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,pos,size,style,name)

    self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self,wx.ID_ANY)
    self.panel.SetScrollbars(1,1,1,1)

    num = 4
    cols = 3
    rows = int(math.ceil(num / 3.0))
    sizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=rows,cols=cols)

    #you should use dict and map all id's to image files
    filenames = []

    for i in range(num):
        filenames.append("img"+str(i)+".png")
    for imgid,fn in enumerate(filenames):
        img = wx.Image(fn,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        img2 = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)

        #pass the imgid here

        img3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel,imgid,img2)
        sizer.Add(img3)
        img3.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK,self.OnDClick)

    self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.Fit()

def OnDClick(self, event):

    print 'you clicked img%s'%(event.GetId() )
```

You can use dict and map every file name to id, by this way you will keep track of it all through your programe.